# U brace/bracket to hold vertical 2x4 over wood floor?

Tags: wood, deck, woodworking, decking

Is there some type of 2x4 brace or bracket that will hold down a “standing” 2x4 on a wood floor?

Here’s a very rudimentary drawing, and the brace Im looking for is in red in the corner.

I know I can use L-brackets or pocket screws, but Im looking for something that will push it down.

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the floor from underneath?

Comment: Pocket screws will push it down very nicely.  They seem perfect if you need some extra downwards force for some reason.   Normally, gravity would hold it down and L brackets would hold it up.    Can you explain a little more why none of those things would work for you?   You could make vertical "pockets" by drilling through the top with deep recesses for small-headed screws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a header, this connector from the Simpson Strong-Tie could be what you need.

[image]